# C# is forcing me to explicitly cast when it shouldn't, why?

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following code:

```
public enum rkError : int {EC_SUCCESS,
    EC_INVALID_FILE, 
    EC_UNDEFINED_HEADER, 
    EC_FILE_NOT_FOUND, 
    EC_CANNOT_CREATE};
```

...then, latter on:

```
int ok;
.
.
.
ok = hdr.Load();
if(ok!=rkError.EC_SUCCESS) return ok;
.
.
.
```

...as far as I understand, both **ok** and **rkError.EC_SUCCESS** are **int**, however the compiler complaints:

Error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'test.rkError'

so in order to run my program I must change the if line like this:

```
if(ok!=(int) rkError.EC_SUCCESS) return ok;
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I took care of explicitly define rkError as **int**.

I'm using MonoDevelop instead of Visual Studio. Is this normal? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`rkError` is not `int`. It's an enum backed by `int`. That's not the same.

And yes, you have to cast enum value to underlying primitive type to compare it with another primitive value.

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid casting? I'm really using enum here because I can't find something equivalent to #define in C/C++.

Comment: Make your `Load` method return `rkError` instead of `int`.

Comment: `const static int EC_SUCCESS = 0;` is a closer analog to `#define` than `enum`.

Comment: @PeterGluck it works only inside the class in which EC_SUCCESS is declared, outside it (in another project), the compiler still requires me to cast. I could quite easily solve this in C/C++, but in C# I am lost.

Comment: C# is a different language to C++, with different rules and syntax. Not *everything* in C++ has a syntactically equivalent analog in C#.

Comment: @georgeb Add the `public` modifier and you can access the constant from anywhere by prepending the class name, e.g., `rkError.EC_SUCCESS`.